# Get a numpy array out of a GeoDataFrame of shapely Points in shapely >=2.0

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, numpy, geos

I had the following code in [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) `1.8.5.post1` which was working but was throwing a warning:

```py
import os
os.environ['USE_PYGEOS'] = '0'
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

pointList = [
    Point(0,0,2),
    Point(0,1,2),
    Point(1,0,2)
]

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pointList, geometry=0)
gdf.rename_geometry('geometry',inplace=True)

c = np.stack(gdf.geometry.apply(np.array))

print(c)
>:
[[0. 0. 2.]
 [0. 1. 2.]
 [1. 0. 2.]]
```

and the warning:

```py
 /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/apply.py:1105: ShapelyDeprecationWarning:
  The array interface is deprecated and will no longer work in Shapely 2.0.
  Convert the '.coords' to a numpy array instead.
    return self.apply_standard()
```

Hence my question: how exactly could I apply the `.coords` method in this code to achieve the exact same result?

Because as is, in shapely `2.0.0`, the output is not a [numpy](https://numpy.org/) array:

```py
print(c)
>:
[<POINT Z (0 0 2)> <POINT Z (0 1 2)> <POINT Z (1 0 2)>]
```

Also, `gdf.geometry.apply(np.array)` and `gdf.geometry` are giving the exact same result in Shapely `2.0.0`, so applying `np.array` on the geometry doesn't seem to have any effect:

```py
>: 
0    POINT Z (0.00000 0.00000 2.00000)
1    POINT Z (0.00000 1.00000 2.00000)
2    POINT Z (1.00000 0.00000 2.00000)
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call xyz directly instead of mapping to a function:

```
c = np.stack([gdf.geometry.x, gdf.geometry.y, gdf.geometry.z], axis=1)

print(c)
# array([[0., 0., 2.],
#        [0., 1., 2.],
#        [1., 0., 2.]])
```

Comment: Oh, this is great! My guess is that this probably runs significantly quicker than the other solutions proposed here because it doesn't rely on the `apply` method, which can be pretty slow at times. Good job =)

Answer (score 2):

You can take your approach and bundle it into a lambda function instead of defining a whole new function:

```py
c = np.stack(gdf.geometry.apply(lambda x: np.array(x.coords).ravel()))

print(c)
#array([[0., 0., 2.],
#       [0., 1., 2.],
#       [1., 0., 2.]])
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of lambdas but this is a nice trick. I'm sad things became a little less pythonic than with the previous Shapely version.

Comment: Yeah, and it just looks real ugly. I;d take a look at [this other answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/450691/123828). It's pythonic and probably executes much faster than this one.

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround in shapely `2.0.0`:

```py
def get_array(geom):
    if isinstance(geom, Point):
        arr = np.array(geom.coords).ravel()

    return arr


c = np.stack(gdf.geometry.apply(get_array))

print(c)
>:
[[0. 0. 2.]
 [0. 1. 2.]
 [1. 0. 2.]]
```

But I am not 100% satisfied with it because I have to create a custom function.

Answer (score 1):

The standard and probably fastest way to do this using shapely 2 would be to use [shapely.get_coordinates](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.get_coordinates.html#shapely.get_coordinates) I think, like this:

```
import os
os.environ["USE_PYGEOS"] = "0"
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Point

points = {"geometry": [Point(0, 0, 2), Point(0, 1, 2), Point(1, 0, 2)]}
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points)
c = shapely.get_coordinates(gdf.geometry, include_z=True)

print(c)
```

Result:

```
[[0. 0. 2.]
[0. 1. 2.]
[1. 0. 2.]]
```